# Redux reducer promise handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I'm experimenting with redux async actions. I have simple react counter App with an action creator for `ASYNC_INCREMENT`:

```
export const asyncIncrement = () => ({
  type: 'ASYNC_INCREMENT',
  payload: api.number.getNumber(),
})
```

With reducer:

```
function counter(state = 0, { type, payload }) {
  switch (type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1
    case 'ASYNC_INCREMENT':
      payload
        .then(({data}) => data)
        .then(({ number }) => {
          number + state
        })
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1
    default:
      return state
  }
}
export default counter
```

I know that is completely wrong, but me is interesting, why in this case then i fire up my `ASYNC_INCREMENT` action, my `state` transforms to `state - 1`. For example: was 9, became 8 and etc.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's due to the behavior of switch statements. You have no `return` or `break` in `case 'ASYNC_INCREMENT':`, so the code continues on to `case 'DECREMENT':`, where it returns `state - 1`

As you may know, reducers have to be synchronous, so it is not correct to do promise-based things in a reducer. You'll need to use an async middleware to do async things. Common examples include [Redux-Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), [Redux-Saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/), and [Redux-Observable](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable). Redux-thunk is the one [recommended by the redux style guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-thunks-for-async-logic).

Comment: You don't have to jump into async middleware right away. For something as simple as this you can handle the async in the handler and then fire the action:
`
export const asyncIncrement = () =>
 api.number.getNumber()
        .then(({data}) => data)
        .then(({ number }) => {
  type: 'INCREMENT',
  payload: number,
})
`